# encephalitis vaccine in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, health-care, health

I have moved to Switzerland a few months ago and, as I come from the south of EU I was not been vaccinated against encephalitis (FSME) when I was a kid. Where can I get the vaccine in Switzerland?

Comment: Don't you have a physician yet? That's the best place to ask

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't have one here yet. But I will call, thank you